# Xamarin.Forms Entry Text is added but not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image]

I'm making a Pin Validator when starting the Application. This is my code:

```
   <ContentPage.Content>


        <StackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0" >
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.3*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowSpacing>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="20"  iOS="20"  />
                </Grid.RowSpacing>

                <Grid.ColumnSpacing>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="20"  iOS="20"  />
                </Grid.ColumnSpacing>

                <Frame BorderColor="#006BE6"  BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
                    <Entry TextColor="#006BE6"  FontSize="48" IsPassword="True" x:Name="Output" Text="{Binding Pin}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:EntryLengthValidatorBehavior MaxLength="4" />
                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                    </Entry>
                </Frame>



                <Button TextColor="#006BE6" Text="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="1" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"    />

                <Button TextColor="#006BE6" Text="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="2" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>
                <Button TextColor="#006BE6" Text="3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="3" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>

                <Button TextColor="#006BE6"  Text="4" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="4" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>
                <Button TextColor="#006BE6"  Text="5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="5" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>
                <Button  TextColor="#006BE6" Text="6" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="6" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>


                <Button TextColor="#006BE6"  Text="7" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="7" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>
                <Button TextColor="#006BE6" Text="8" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="8" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>
                <Button TextColor="#006BE6" Text="9" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="9" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>

                <Button TextColor="#006BE6" Text="C" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="C"  BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>
                <Button TextColor="#006BE6" Text="0" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="0" BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>
                <Button TextColor="#006BE6" Text="OK" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding LoadNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="OK"  BorderColor="#006BE6" BorderWidth="1" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"/>

            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Everything is working fine just text in the Entry is not showing. My idea is add 4 digit pin . Binding Pin get values from the numbers but not showing in the Entry. I don't know what is the problem. Someone help?

In the ViewModel in added Pin and Command

```
 public string pin;
        public string Pin
        {
            get { return pin; }
            set
            {
                if (pin != value)
                {
                    pin = value;

                    SetProperty(ref pin, value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Pin");

                }
            }
        }
```

and the Command

```
LoadNumberCommand = new Command(execute: async (value) => await ExecutePinElement(value));
```

Comment: can you be more specific? is the text that's not showing or the entry itself?

Comment: Binding Pin  is working . In Pin i got numbers which i added but the numbers or Password * * * * not showing

Comment: Its the text  i will edit with screenshot

Comment: can you show EntryLengthValidatorBehavioryour ?

Comment: Add a grid.row = "1" and Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" to the entry box

Comment: please show the code for your VM.  Does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes i implemented INotify. In VM  Pin get the numbers on every execution of the command. Example i have in PIN : 12 but not showing in the entry

Comment: public string pin;
        public string Pin
        {
            get { return pin; }
            set
            {
                if (pin != value)
                {
                    pin = value;

                    SetProperty(ref pin, value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Pin");

                }
            }
        }

Comment: Make sure that your `TextColor` is not playing mind games with you!!!

Comment: Probably the fontsize is so big

Comment: Try to put the entry inside a stacklayout and set the Frame to IsClipedToBounds="True", to see if the entry is really inside the frame bounds

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais can you send code example?

Comment: <Frame IsClipedToBounds="True" ...  | and <StackLayout> //Your Entry Here </StackLayout>

Comment: Its because of the fontsize . But now with default fontsize showing only 2 * like this * * and other 2 * not showing

Comment: I added now WidthRequest="100" i show all but not centralized dont look good

Comment: you could look at the [official demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#using-command-parameters),it's similar to your project,i meet the same issue with you first,but it works when i create a new empty project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Entry's `IsReadOnly`property to false

or

chage the `HorizontalOptions` to `"FillAndExpand"` and Add `HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"`

Comment: FillAndExpand solved my problem , i was center and not showing all the text , thank you

Comment: happy to help =)